# Improve the Default Off-Topic Close Reason

Tags: discussion, off-topic, close-reasons

Our default off-topic is currently:

> This question does not appear to be about $Topic within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

I find "webmastering" as the `$Topic` to be fairly awkward.   I'd like to change this wording.

Moderators can edit this reason [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic).  The help on this page has this to say about this close reason:

> Shown when no 2 off-topic reasons match on a closed question.

So this isn't a close reason that users can select from a list, this is shown when consensus on the close reason can't be reached.

Please answer if you have a suggestion of what you would like this message to be.  I have a suggestion of my own.

Answer (score 1):

> This question does not appear to be about running a website.  For guidance on which questions are on-topic on Pro Webmasters, please see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I don't know if changing "Webmastering" to "running a website" is substantially any better. The second sentence is an improvement, though, as it guides to user to click on the link instead of assuming they'd just want to because it is there.

Comment: @JohnConde while not substantially any better, it is more clear, especially given that for a percentage of users English is not their primary language.

Comment: I think off topic and holds could be better described. For one, it's probably frustrating to new users who think they asked a good question and have their thread shut down. A lot of them probably don't come back to participate on the site because of it. Also, a lot of questions get put on hold for reasons that I don't understand, and so an elaboration for why it's beneficial to the site to put these questions on hold would be helpful to me as well.